# Rails Validations presence when relation model is created but not saved

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models **Task** and **DependecyTask** and they have a relation between them well clear on the code.

When I try to save a **Task**, the validation *task presence: true* of **DependencyTask Task attribute** give the error that you can see, because the **Task** model is not saved yet.

How I can solve this problem, without remove validates :task?

Models:

```
class DependencyTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task
  belongs_to :before, :class_name => "Task"

  validates :before, presence: true
  validates :task, presence: true
  validates :before_id, uniqueness: {scope: :task_id,
    message: "No puede ser la misma tarea dependiente de si misma"}

end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assignment_tasks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :assignment_tasks

  has_many :dependency_tasks, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :befores, :through => :dependency_tasks
  has_many :inverse_dependency_tasks, :class_name => "DependencyTask", :foreign_key => "before_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :inverse_befores, :through => :inverse_dependency_tasks, :source => :task

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :dependency_tasks

end
```

Controller:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

def create
    @task = @project.tasks.create(params[:task].permit(:name, :length, :start_date, :end_date, :milestone_id, :description, {before_ids: []}, {user_ids: []}, :form => [] ))
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save        
        format.html { redirect_to project_path(@project) }
        format.json { redirect_to 'edit', status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'index' }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

Data sended to server:

```
Processing by TasksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"âœ“", "authenticity_token"=>"fYRkppGw8ekRS3aBMwKSw8IU+8ayBdUKDw20/QT0r/g=", "task"=>{"name"=>"Architecture building and Cost estimate", "length"=>"20", "start_date"=>"16/01/2015", "end_date"=>"30/01/2015", "description"=>"", "milestone_id"=>"", "before_ids"=>["", "6"]}, "commit"=>"Crear Tarea", "locale"=>"es", "project_id"=>"8"}
```

Error:

```
["Dependency tasks task Can't be blank"]
{
    :"dependency_tasks.task" => [
        [0] "Can't be blank"
    ]
}
```

All helpful comments will be really apreciated.

Comment: Are you using Observers?

Comment: I don't know what is this

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem using inverse_of method

Models:

```
class DependencyTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task, inverse_of: :dependency_tasks
  belongs_to :before, :class_name => "Task", inverse_of: :dependency_tasks

end



class Task < ActiveRecord::Base   

  has_many :dependency_tasks, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :task
  has_many :befores, :through => :dependency_tasks, inverse_of: :dependency_tasks
  has_many :inverse_dependency_tasks, :class_name => "DependencyTask", :foreign_key => "before_id", dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :task
  has_many :inverse_befores, :through => :inverse_dependency_tasks, :source => :task, inverse_of: :inverse_dependency_tasks
end
```